# How can I make a "light cms" with PHP?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I really don't want to use any software, I want to learn by myself. Nothing like WordPress though. All it is, user goes to example.com/login. and they enter a password. After that all they see is Mark down text-editor. They put in content then click enter. then it generates to the page.  Creating a short summery for the front of the page then having a link to the whole page.

How would I accomplish this? Any tutorials?

Comment: In a framework or with vanilla PHP?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. You need to approach this one problem at a time. Sit down and work out what functionality you need in this CMS. Once you have that, do some research on how to solve the particular problem. ie. I need to implement markdown into my text field. Or how do I structure my database. You can then ask actual questions. SO users can't provide a working CMS for you. If you google "how to create a cms in php" there are lots and lots of basic tutorials which should help you get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a basic PHP/MySQL tutorial. Here's an good one:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_intro.asp

Once you get through that, building a simple CMS will be a snap.